# Import module (rasterio) fail with conda or pip install

Tags: python, rasterio

I am trying to install rasterio into my python environment and am getting the following errors.  I can do

```
    conda install rasterio
```

No error comes up on the install but I come up with the following error when I try to import

```
    from rasterio._base import eval_window, window_shape, window_index

    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

if I try

```
    pip install rasterio
```

it errors when installing with this:

```
    rasterio/_base.c(263) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:'cpl_conv.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Rdebbout\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
    Failed building wheel for rasterio
```

I have the same problems with trying to import the fiona module. How and/or where do DLLs get loaded?  I'm in the dark on this one and would appreciate any help or direction as to how to troubleshoot this problem.

I am using the 64-bit version of spyder on windows 7.

Comment: It looks like the setup script can't find a header file that it needs. [This answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip) from the GIS Stack Exchange may solve your problem.

Comment: when you say 'setup script' are you referring to a script titled 'setup.py' in the site-packages folder?  There is no such script in that folder

Comment: That's what I meant, so obviously *that's* not it, but I expect `pip` is doing something similar behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying the ioos anaconda recipe (https://anaconda.org/ioos/rasterio).

`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/ioos rasterio`.

I have run into the same DLL issue you are seeing when trying to install more recent versions of rasterio using the standard anaconda version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. A reinstall solved it.

```
conda install -f rasterio
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're still having the issue. you can create a new conda enviroment using:

```
conda create -n envname
```

After that install using: `conda install -c conda-forge/label/dev rasterio`